# Prevent body from being dragged from above by a second moving body in MatterJS

Tags: p5.js, matter.js

I'm trying to make a quick little game with matter.js and p5.js. I have a player, which is moveable through arrow keys. I also have a second box that spawns right below the player. I've noticed that the 2nd box moves when I move the player left and right on top of it.

[image: How do I stop that 2nd box from getting moved?]

How can I stop this from happening? I only want the 2nd box to be moveable by pushing it left or right, not by moving on top of it.

I think friction is causing it to be moved. I've tried removing friction from nonstatic bodies when the player is on top of it, but that also removes friction for the player. I want the player to still experience the same friction on top of that 2nd box, without moving it in the process.

Also, removing friction from only the topside of the 2nd box may fix the issue, but I don't know how to do that.

Code:

```js
let Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Runner = Matter.Runner,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Body = Matter.Body,
    Composite = Matter.Composite;

let engine;

let boxDim = 100;
let boxA;
let player;
let friction = 0.1;

let platforms = [];
let isGrounded = false;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(800, 520);

  // create an engine
  engine = Engine.create();

  // create two boxes and a ground
  boxA = Bodies.rectangle(400, 200, boxDim, boxDim, {
    mass: 20
  });
  platforms.push(boxA);

  player = Bodies.rectangle(400, 50, boxDim, boxDim, {
    mass: 20,
    friction
  });
  Body.setInertia(player, Infinity);
  
  ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 510, 810, 60, {
    isStatic: true
  });
  platforms.push(ground);

  // add all of the bodies to the world
  World.add(engine.world, [boxA, player, ground]);

  let runner = Runner.create();
  Runner.run(runner, engine);
}

// Using p5 to render
function draw() {

  background(51);
  keyDown();

  noStroke();
  
  drawShape(boxA);
  drawShape(player);
  drawShape(ground, 127);
}

// Movement code and rendering - You can ignore this

function drawShape(body, color = 225) {
  beginShape();
  fill(color);
  for (let vertice of body.vertices) {
    vertex(vertice.x, vertice.y);
  }
  endShape();
}

function keyPressed() {
  let jumpHeight = 14;
  
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    Body.setVelocity(player, {x:player.velocity.x, y:-jumpHeight})
  }
}

function keyDown() {
  let velocity = 12;
  let targetX = player.velocity.x;

  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
    targetX = velocity;
  } else if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
    targetX = -velocity;
  } else {
    targetX = 0;
  }
  targetX = lerp(player.velocity.x, targetX, 0.1);
  Body.setVelocity(player, {x: targetX, y: player.velocity.y});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.18.0/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

You can also go to https://replit.com/@CrazyVideoGamer/Stop-player-from-moving-2nd-box-from-above and fork it.

Comment: @zazz I'm pretty sure it doesn't because it doesn't talk about removing friction and whatnot. It only talks about weird collisions

Comment: @zazz I want it to collide with the 2nd box, so that doesn't work either. It's a friction problem, not a collision problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I think friction is causing it to be moved

That is correct. If there's friction, moving the top box while it's sitting on the bottom box will also apply a "pull" like force on the bottom box.

> Removing friction from only the topside of the 2nd box may fix the issue, but I don't know how to do that

You'll need to remove friction from both the top side of the bottom box and the bottom side of the top box. You can create a custom Box class with consists of four rectangles, representing each side. Set the thickness of the rectangles to something small and it should appear as a line. You'll need to write a custom draw function, but it will allow you to have different friction options for each side.

Comment: But what if I still want the player to move at the same speed walking on dynamic objects compared to static objects?